# How can i run automated selenium tests using TFS build 2015?

Tags: c#, selenium, tfs

I have NUnit selenium tests that i have embedded into Unit test and i am trying to run this using TFS Build 2015. All the tests run perfectly fine locally but not from the TFS Server. I enabled code coverage and found out that "Module unittests.dll" works fine and most of the code is covered but for "Seleniumtest.exe" 0 lines covered.

I have read a lot on this problem and came across the idea of enabling the TFS Agent to run in interactive mode but i do not know how to do this from the TFS Server and most of the documentation online is not good enough.Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the Hosted agent queue, you can't. If you have your own on-premise build agent, you just need to run the agent from a command prompt (as opposed to as a service). That's all that "interactive" means.

You can also use the [Test Agent tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DeployVisualStudioTestAgent/README.md) to deploy a test agent to a target machine and invoke the tests on them. This will also allow you to run UI tests even if you're using the hosted agent queue -- you'll be passing off the running of the tests to an on-premise test agent.

On a side note, you should generally **not** run UI tests as part of a build process, but rather as a step in a release pipeline after the application has been released to a QA environment. UI tests are slow and brittle, and you don't want your CI process to be bogged down with running UI tests.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I was just weighing up whether the headaches of attempting to automate (my already slightly brittle) Selenium testing would be worth it, but your last paragraph was all the convincing I needed not to bother!