# Associate automated tests Robotframework with test cases in TFS

Tags: selenium, tfs, robotframework

I am working using TFS to create test case. I have a automated test written in Robotframework with Selenium2Library.

I'd like to be able to associate these tests with test cas in test. Is it possible to link the automated test cases  with the test case in TFS, and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

The web Test page does not support to run automatic tests associated with test cases in TFS.

You can achieve the same goals using the Build & Release features in Team Foundation Server (TFS). (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/use-build-or-rm-instead-of-lab-management). Simply integrate Selenium  testing into a continuous integration/continuous delivery pipeline.

Instead of build, suggest you use a step in a release pipeline. Take a look at this question:[How can i run automated selenium tests using TFS build 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583291/how-can-i-run-automated-selenium-tests-using-tfs-build-2015)

[image]

More detail steps about how to integrate with TFS please go through the official tutorials from MSDN: **[Get started with Selenium testing in a CD pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=vsts)**